# Scrolling Div to offset of Child relative to Itself

Tags: javascript, jquery

For my project I have a gigantic multi-level menu that floats to the left of the page on mobile.  I'm looking for a way to scroll the level clicked in the menu to the top of the menu's div, but I am having trouble getting the offset of the child relative to the menu in order to scroll the div to that point.

I've put together a fiddle of the problem I am having that you can see here:

http://jsfiddle.net/L449H/1/

Since offset() gets the position of the element relative to the window, that won't work because I'll only get the distance from the window to the element.  Using position doesn't work either because elements that have been scrolled outside of the viewable area return a negative number, so traversing the dom and getting the total position() offset doesn't work either.

How can I make this work? I need a way to find the distance in pixels from the top of my menu div and the top of the item that was clicked with the position of the browser's window completely ignored.

The fiddle is set up with just some example code that demonstrates the problem.  My actual DOM is set up like this using angular if anybody needs a specific reference:

```
<div data-ng-controller="MenuController">

    <script type="text/ng-template" id="menu_item_renderer.html">
        <span class="menu-item">
            <a ng-show="category.link" href="{{category.link}}" class="menu-item-title">
                {{category.title}}
            </a>
            <span ng-show="!category.link" class="menu-item-title">
                {{category.title}}
            </span>
            <span class="menu-toggle-btn"><i class="icon-plus" /></span>
        </span>
        <ul class="menu-category-list list-unstyled">
            <li data-ng-repeat="category in filtered = (category.categories | linkFilter:selectedFilters:searchTerm)" data-ng-class="hasChildren()" data-ng-include="'menu_item_renderer.html'" class="menu-category"></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="menu-link-list list-unstyled">
            <li data-ng-repeat="link in filtered = (category.links | linkFilter:selectedFilters:searchTerm)" class="menu-link">
                <span class="menu-item">
                    <a href="{{link.link}}" class="menu-item-title">{{link.title}}</a>
                </span>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </script>

    <div id="global-menu" class="menu ng-cloak" data-features="globalMenu">
        <div id="global-menu-tools">
            <div id="global-menu-search">
                <label>Search</label><br>
                <input type="text" data-ng-model="searchTerm" />
            </div>

            <div id="global-menu-filters">
                <label>Filters</label>
                <div class="filter" data-ng-repeat="filter in menu.filters">
                    <label>{{filter.title}}</label>
                    <input type="checkbox" data-ng-click="setSelectedFilter()" />
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
        <ul class="menu-categories list-unstyled">
            <li class="menu-category" data-ng-repeat="category in menu.categories" data-ng-include="'menu_item_renderer.html'"  data-on-finish-render></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to take into account the #menu scrollTop position too:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/L449H/2/)

```
$("#menu").animate({scrollTop: $("#menu").scrollTop() + $(this).position().top});
```

Which is the same as:

```
$("#menu").animate({scrollTop: "+="+ $(this).position().top});
```